# Xml Serializer Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to use the xml serializer in my xna game for wp7. The XmlSerializer class will not work in my game. The compiler doesn't recognize the class. And yes I have added:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
```

Why wont it recognize the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Xml.Serialization.dll`.
It's not in the `System.Xml.dll` and it isn't in the default game template.